# Shelljs exec() not executing variables

Tags: javascript, node.js, shelljs

Shelljs exec command doesnot take variables. I tried all possible combinations like using double quotes, single quotes, assigning $ in front of the variable etc.
below is the script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
require('shelljs');
for(let i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
{
  let dev = data[i];
  let platform_version = exec('adb -s $dev', {silent:false}).stdout;
}
```

error : dev not found or adds all the help commands of adb and prints out.

can anyone please help ? Thanks

note: adb is an android tool. you can use any simple commandline like echo etc

Comment: Can you try something like this - exec('adb -s ' + dev, {silent:false}).stdout;

Comment: This works only if the variable is placed at the end. Not sure how to get it working when a variable is in between the shell command. I posted the answer using template literals

Answer (score 2):

You cannot do string interpolation in JavaScript like `'adb -s $dev'`. The `$dev` variable will not be replaced by its value. You can use the `+` operator instead to form the string. See the code below.

```
let platform_version = exec('adb -s ' + dev, {silent:false}).stdout;
```

Note:
In ECMAScript 6, you can use [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) to get similar result since they allow string interpolation. Template literals are written within `` ` `` (backticks). Which means the code `` `adb -s ${dev}` `` should also give the desired result.

Comment: Thanks Vivek for the answer. Used Template literals to solve the issue but you need to wrap the variable in curly braces.

Comment: @Indra4ev3r Yes, missed the curly braces. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 1):

Using Template Literals we can solve the issue. But there is a small change in the variables.

```
let platform_version = exec(`adb -s ${dev}`, {silent:false}).stdout;
```

Need to use wrap the variable in curly braces to get the desired result.